# module has no exported member error angular package.json

Tags: angular

so i am trying to add a custom field in my package.json as config for one of my component to use. but I receive this error:

module has no exported member error angular package.json

here is my code:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "myfield": "my value",
.....
}
```

here is my component import:

```
import { config, version } from '../../../../../package.json';
```

I found out that this config field receive the error. but version field is actually OKAY.

Why is that and what should I do if i want to add config value.(just a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package.json file is not meant to be imported and used as a module in your Angular application.

To add a custom configuration value for your Angular application, you should use environment files or configuration services.

In your Angular project, create a new environment file. For example, you can create a file called environment.ts in the src/environments folder if it doesn't already exist.

```
// src/environments/environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  myConfigValue: 'my value',
};
```

In your component, you can import the configuration value like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent {
  configValue = environment.myConfigValue;
}
```